# VueJS rendering data from REST service

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, vue.js, vuex

I've attempted to render data from a http request to a component which is working fine, the issue is that it's null while the data is being fetched. While the data is null the console is throwing a TypeError until all the data is loaded and committed to the Vuex store.

All is working how I'd suspect, I'm just trying to figure how I can prevent the errors being thrown and to wait until all the appropriate data is fetched. I've seen others using v-if to check if the data is null which will work. It just seems tedious and that there surly is a better way to achieve the same outcome, without an application riddled with v-if statements checking every single state.

I came across this solution but it's still not working how I thought it would, I'm still receiving the same console errors. Am I using these key words correctly and are they in the correct location? since nothing has changed with every variation I've tried.

Vuex Action:

```js
const actions = {
  getThread ({ commit }, payload) {
    Vue.http
      .get(`http://localhost:9000/threads/${payload.id}`)
      .then(async response => {
        commit(FETCH_THREAD, await response.data)
      })
  }
}
```

This is within my vue file calling upon the action:

```js
created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('getThread', {id: '59280ab5acbafb17af9da902'})
  }
```

Comment: Look at this ( https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html ).

Comment: @VAMSIKRISHNA I did look into this too but it was producing the same errors in the console.

Comment: Why is it `async-await`? When `get` is resolved in `.then` you've already received the data. Besides, mutations can only be synchronous, so this async-await commit doesn't make sense if I'm not missing something.

Comment: @wostex Thats where I'm confused, I was just following along with this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609155/vuex-rendering-data-that-is-fetched-from-rest-api where the same issue arised.

Comment: There async-await is used on actions, not mutations. It's a different case there. In order to avoid render errors while your data is not fetched, just use guards in you templates: `v-if="mydata && mydata.length"` for an array for example.

Comment: @wostex just looking back this, am I able to use beforeRouteEnter to load the data in with the dispatch, then once that loaded and I call next then render in the view where all the data is loaded prior?

Comment: @Jordan I don't know about that, have a try. There's an official example for this case: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/navigation-guards/app.js - line 57 is the most interesting for you.

Comment: @wostex I did see that, I played around with it but it couldn't get it working with vuex, at least in a nice clean approach. v-if it is I guess.

Comment: @Jordan usually it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are trying to display something from your store in your template. The problem is, Vue cannot render something that does not exist yet. The solution is to check whether the data exists or not.

Let's take this component example:

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ someObject.name }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                someObject: null
            }
        },
        methods: {
            fetchTheObject () {
                this.someObject = {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'My object'
                }
            }
        },
        created () {
            setTimeout( () => {
                this.fetchTheObject()
            }, 3000)
        }
    }
</script>
```

As you can see, you will get an error in your console because `someObject.name` does not exist until `fetchTheObject()` has been called.

The solution is to put some `v-if` attribute to control that:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <span v-if="someObject === null">Fetching the object</span>
        <span v-else>{{ someObject.name }}</span>
    </div>
</template>
```

In general, you would want to display some spinner to show the user that something is loading...

Hope this helps

EDIT: And forget about the async await in your code, you don't need that here

Comment: And what would one do if there is data after 3000?

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: You set the timeout for `3000` to wait the data. What if in real world scenario there wouldn't be the data after 3000?

Comment: In the real world, you are supposed to make an ajax request, that is supposed to either succeed or fail. You should then adapt this model to a success/failure scenario. For example, adding a "fetching_error" variable and displaying some message if this fetching_error is set to something